# Why can't I create a file in a directory with permissions 777?

Tags: permissions, android, chmod

I've got a directory on an Android device that I've set to permission 777.  But as a non-root user while I can touch existing files with these permissions, I can't create new files.

```
$ ls -la
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 60 2022-02-05 11:11 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 60 2022-02-05 10:23 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  0 2022-02-05 11:12 a.txt
$ touch a.txt
$ ls -la
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 60 2022-02-05 11:11 .
drwxrwxrwx 3 root root 60 2022-02-05 10:23 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  0 2022-02-05 11:14 a.txt
```

The timestamp changed showing that I was able to touch the file. (I can also cat >> the file and that works as well.) Now I try to create a new file.

```
$ touch b.txt
touch: 'b.txt': Permission denied
```

Why can't I create new files since the directory permissions (777) should give anybody the ability to modify the directory?  I also tried setting the directory permissions to 1777 but that did not fix the problem.  If I try to cat >> the file I get the same error:

```
/system/bin/sh: can't create b.txt: Permission denied
```

I have tried creating a file from several different locations including an app on the phone, an ssh shell, and an adb shell.

I was reading elsewhere that there might be extended attributes, but the "attr" command doesn't seem to exist.

```
# attr
/system/bin/sh: attr: inaccessible or not found
```

But, I created and permissions this directory myself (as root) so I wouldn't expect there to *be* any extended attributes!

Update:

Running `strace touch b.txt` yields these lines around the failure:

```
utimensat(AT_FDCWD, "b.txt", NULL, 0)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "b.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
write(2, "touch: b.txt: Permission denied\n", 32touch: b.txt: Permission denied
```

) = 32

(The last one is obviously where it prints the error)

Comment: Where is that directory? What is the filesystem?

Comment: @yarl it's on a tmpfs I created with options `rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,mode=777`

Comment: Can you use `strace` as in `strace touch b.txt`?

Comment: Oh and please add all these info by editing your question. Not in comments.

Comment: @yarl I'm not sure how much of this is relevant. I'll include the calls in the vicinity of the failure.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381070/permission-denied-even-though-i-own-it-and-permissions-are-777?rq=1

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/469825/60747 might help. Your question is a little unclear, at the top you say you "have" a directory and it has a file a.txt in but then you say you can't create files, only touch them; then you say you made this directory ... so that means you made the file a.txt already?? Android has special directories, I think, that you can't modify without rooting the phone; but that wouldn't apply if you made this directory, but I can't tell from your question. Did you make the directory and the a.txt file. What is the full path and proper name of a.txt?

Comment: @pbhj I created the directory as root, mounted a tmpfs on it, and created `a.txt`.  I then set the permissions so that everyone should be able to modify a.txt and create files in the directory with it.

Comment: @yarl Unfortunately the answers to that question don't help me.

Comment: @pbhj The first answer is talking about anti-virus which isn't applicable here.  The second one mentions lsattr (which shouldn't apply because I didn't create any extended attributes) but if I try to run it on the file or dir I see this in strace: `ioctl(4, FS_IOC_GETFLAGS, 0x7fd7c83b4c) = -1 ENOTTY (Not a typewriter)`

Comment: If your mount point isn't user writable/accessible (ie the dir where you attach the [in this case tmpfs] filesystem) then the dir mounted there won't be either, so despite the directory and the mount being mode=777 you might still not be able to write. That could be it. `df -a` should list the mount points in the right-hand column (or `findmnt` in the left tree).